# Repeatable-random TikZ shapes - least amount of code to produce starting from specifying each coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created an image that I am happy with but want to expand my `tikz` knowledge - I do not know how to create somewhat random but consistent shapes within my `tikz` picture. The final image looks as follows:

[image]

I have had to specify everything in the diagram, including where lines from "Amidohydrolases" connects to the sphere. What is a better way to draw this diagram without having to specify every coordinate please?

```
\RequirePackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{Arial}[ItalicFont=ariali.ttf,BoldFont=arialbd.ttf,BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf]
\newcommand\Denovo{\textit{De novo}}

\begin{document}
%
\footnotesize%
%
\tikzset{%
    dotted_ellipse/.style={draw=black!80!white, line width=0.5pt, dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt,%
            inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=-2pt, ellipse}%
}%
%
\definecolor{myblack}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}%
%
\newcommand\circleColour{Bisque2}%
%
\newcommand\medEL{5}%
\newcommand\medEW{3}%
\newcommand\smallEL{2.5}%
\newcommand\biggerEL{5.5}%
\newcommand\smallEW{1.35}%
\newcommand\biggerEW{3.5}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    background/.style   = {ultra thin,color=DodgerBlue3},%
    small ellipse/.style   ={color=\circleColour},%
    med ellipse/.style    ={color=\circleColour},%
    bigger ellipse/.style ={color=\circleColour},%
    max ellipse/.style    ={color=\circleColour},%
    ]%
%
\filldraw[background] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (16,3) -- (16,0) -- (0,0);%
%
\node [anchor=west,text width=1.11cm,inner ysep=0.1pt] (native) at (16.3,2.66) {\textcolor{myblack}{Native \\ enzymes}};%
\node [anchor=west,text width=1.11cm,inner ysep=0.6pt] (ratdes) at (16.3,1.05) {\textcolor{myblack}{Rational \\ design}};%
\node [anchor=west,text width=1.11cm,inner ysep=0.1pt] (direvo) at (16.3,1.87) {\textcolor{myblack}{Directed \\ evolution}};%
\node [anchor=west,text width=1.1cm,inner ysep=0pt] (denovo) at (16.3,0.29) {%
    \textcolor{myblack}{\Denovo\\ design}%
};%
%
\node [anchor=west] (dehy) at (1, 2.75) {\textcolor{white}{\scriptsize\textit{Dehydrogenases}}};%
\node [anchor=west] (urea) at (3.2, 0.27) {\textcolor{white}{\scriptsize\textit{Urease}}};%
\node [anchor=west] (hydro) at (2.1, 0.70) {\textcolor{white}{\scriptsize\textit{Amidohydrolases}}};%
%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (2.1,1.5)         ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (3.1,1.67)       ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (4,2.625)         ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (4.8,0.45)        ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (5,2.325)         ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (6.8,1.35)        ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (7.4,0.6)          ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (7.6,0.625)      ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (8.2,1.72)        ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (9.5,2.25)           ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (9.6,2.025)     ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (9.75,0.825)     ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (10.3,0.9)         ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (10.5,0.72)      ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (10.7,0.8625)   ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (10.75,1.525)   ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (11,1.8)          ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (11.3,1.65)       ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (11.7,1.6125)   ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (12.55,2.6625) ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (14,2.175)        ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (14.4,2.175)     ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
\filldraw[small ellipse] (14.7,2.5875)   ellipse (\smallEL pt and \smallEW pt);%
%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (1.75,1.525) ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (2.1,2.025)   ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (5,0.55)        ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (3.7,2.55)     ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (8,1.35) ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
\draw[dotted_ellipse, name=ratdot] (8,1.35) ellipse (10 pt and 7pt);%
\filldraw[med ellipse] (14.2,2.325) ellipse (\medEL pt and \medEW pt);%
%
\filldraw[bigger ellipse] (2.9,1.5)         ellipse (\biggerEL pt and \biggerEW pt);%
\filldraw[bigger ellipse] (4.7,2.4)         ellipse (\biggerEL pt and \biggerEW pt);%
\filldraw[bigger ellipse] (11.1,0.7125) ellipse (\biggerEL pt and \biggerEW pt);%
%
\filldraw[max ellipse] (13.5,1.65) ellipse (7pt and 5pt);   % Main one
%
\draw[thin] (denovo) -- (13.5,0.45)  node [draw=black, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.4pt, pos=1]  {};%
\draw[thin] (native)   -- (14.2,2.325) node [draw=black, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.4pt, pos=1]  {};%
\draw[thin] (direvo)   -- (13.83,1.65) node [draw=black, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.4pt, pos=1]  {};%
\draw[thin] (ratdes)   -- (8.44,1.350) node [draw=black, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.4pt, pos=1]  {};%
%
\draw[->,thin,-latex,color=white] (dehy.east) -- (3.5,2.6);% 
\draw[->,thin,-latex,color=white] (hydro.east) -- (4.8,0.6);% 
\draw[->,thin,-latex,color=white] (urea.east) -- (4.7,0.43);%
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want it so that it is the same each time, uses minimal (understandable for my level) code, has no overlap of labels and looks pretty spread out to the left and right please. My code uses ~100 lines of code and is far from optimal. Does anyone have a better solution please? I am happy with my image but far from happy with my code, it is ugly. I am compiling with `lualatex` as I need the Arial font for my report.

Comment: Just an idea: if you don't want things to overlap, you could maybe do loop and upon each round add a random number to some variable up to a certain value. You could do this for the *x* and *y* axis and multiply the random number with the max width or max height of the picture(s) you want to place. The result would be some kind of invisible grid where only some cells are filled with your picture(s). To make it even more "random" you could make the grid cells larger and additionally shift the picture inside the cells randomly a bit. Would something like this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea, I don't know whether this could be even something useful: You could use two `\foreach` loops to go stepwise horizontally and vertically over a certain area. The steps are as large that the ellipses you want to place won't ever overlap. At each step, you can use a random function to decide whether a small or a larger ellipse should be place or no ellipse at all. You can additionally use random functions to shift the ellipses inside their "cells" a bit, so that it looks really random.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    medium ellipse/.pic={
        \fill[Bisque2] (0,0) circle[x radius=5pt, y radius=3pt];
    },
    small ellipse/.pic={
        \fill[Bisque2] (0,0) circle[x radius=2.5pt, y radius=1.35pt];
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[DodgerBlue3] (0,0) rectangle (16,3);

    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,15.5} {
        \foreach \y in {0.5,1,...,2.5} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\temprand}{rand}
            \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\temprand > 0.5 && \temprand < 0.75, 1, 0)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                \pic at ([shift={({rand*5pt},{rand*5pt})}]\x,\y) {medium ellipse};
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\temprand > 0.75, 1, 0)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                \pic at ([shift={({rand*5pt},{rand*5pt})}]\x,\y) {small ellipse};
            \fi
        }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naming the `pics` allows you to attach labels to them:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    medium ellipse/.pic={
        \fill[Bisque2] (0,0) circle[x radius=5pt, y radius=3pt];
        \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
    },
    small ellipse/.pic={
        \fill[Bisque2] (0,0) circle[x radius=2.5pt, y radius=1.35pt];
        \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[DodgerBlue3] (0,0) rectangle (16,3);

    \newcounter{pics}
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,15.5} {
        \foreach \y in {0.5,1,...,2.5} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\temprand}{rand}
            \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\temprand > 0.5 && \temprand < 0.75, 1, 0)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                \stepcounter{pics}
                \pic (pic \thepics) at ([shift={({rand*5pt},{rand*5pt})}]\x,\y) {medium ellipse};
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\temprand > 0.75, 1, 0)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                \stepcounter{pics}
                \pic (pic \thepics) at ([shift={({rand*5pt},{rand*5pt})}]\x,\y) {small ellipse};
            \fi
        }
    }

    \draw (pic 7-center) -- (pic 7-center -| -1,0) node[left] {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I know, you can fix a certain (pseudo-)randomly generated pattern using `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`. That is, with a specified `<integer>` your output would always be the same. This might be helpful, if you want to have the ellipses distributed randomly, but still get a fixed reproducable output.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that you can fix a certain randomly generated pattern using `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`. That is, if you use `\pgfmathsetseed{20}` for example, your output would always be the same.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, never used a `\foreach` before in `tikz`, thank you!